# Why do people sneeze when someone talks about them?

Tags: tropes

Where did this trope originate from and why sneezing? It must be something only in Asian culture because I have never seen this in any US television shows. And yet sneezing when being talked about occurs in both anime and dramas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something that got featured in the Book of songs, this was a poem book out of ancient china (1000BC) and still is occasionally found in Anime/Manga now a days

> In certain parts of Eastern Asia, particularly in Japanese culture and Vietnamese culture, a sneeze without an obvious cause was generally perceived as a sign that someone was talking about the sneezer at that very moment - a belief that is still depicted in present-day manga and anime. In China, Vietnam and Japan, for instance, there is a superstition that if talking behind someone's back causes the person being talked about to sneeze; as such, the sneezer can tell if something good is being said (one sneeze), something bad is being said (two sneezes in a row), or if this is a sign that they are about to catch a cold (multiple sneezes).  [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneeze)

Small side note to *"It must be something only in Asian culture because I have never seen this in any US television shows"*. Although not used as often in movies/series nowadays, they still feature this trope once in a while and is mainly used in a comedic sense. A sample would be *Scrubs* and *NCIS* where it got featured a few times.

Comment: I find it incredibly unlikely that the Japanese superstition has anything to do with Greece.

Comment: @senshin As far as I know the sneeze originated from Greece as a sign of the gods. This later on got adopted into other parts of the world such as Asia which gave their own twist. It also might have been China. But I am not sure how the Greek/Chineese calender collide in ancient time.

Comment: Wait a second... your new wiki link explains the origin of the trope. Please correct you answer then I can mark it correct.

Comment: @krikara seems like I totally missed that part ;) added the correct information

Answer (score 0):

In Homers Odyssey Telemachus sneezes when his mother speaks about him or what he is doing. So there is western precedent.